# Using gdm to manage xdmcp authentication over VNC

Tags: fedora, xorg, vnc, gdm

I've followed a few guides in order to enable XDMCP over VNC, however the end result is an ugly, if functional, default X login screen. It is not utilizing gdm for the authentication process, and I think it would look significantly more professional if it were.

This guide helped me the most: http://blog.sarah-happy.ca/2010/10/ubuntu-1010-vnc-login-screen.html

but I also used this guide as a reference: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-multiuserloginsvnc/index.html?ca=drs-&utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter

I am using Fedora 17 Beta, and my goal is to be able to allow multiple users of a single host computer through VNC, with each user receiving a unique desktop that is independent of the other users. Therefore, when a new VNC session is started, it connects to XDM to allow them to login. Everything is working flawlessly except for the login screen looking like it's from the year 1980.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I don't remember if I ever found a fix or not. This was a long time ago. I was just experimenting with the feature, and it worked -- regardless of how ugly the login screen was.